# c# override ToString of MyList<T> not shown in VS

Tags: c#, generics, tostring

I want to have a class derived from `List<T>`, mainly for the purpose to be able to be shown different stuff than the usual `Count = 3` in the debugger of VisualStudio 2012. I thought this would be easy by providing my own overriden ToString() method for my own overriden generic `MyList<T>` class.

It doesn't work though, the overriden ToString() is not called from the debugger and I still get to see the old Count = 3.

Here is the code.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    public class MyList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            int nMax = 100;
            string s = "N:" + this.Count + "; ";
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Count && s.Length < nMax; ++i)
                s += this[i].ToString() + "; ";
            return s;
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyList<string> a = new MyList<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
            Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        }
    } 
}
```

When setting a breakpoint onto the last brace of the Main method, I get to see in the debugger Auto- or Local-window this:
  `a  | Count = 3 |  ConsoleApplication1.MyList<string>`

I want and expected to be shown there: 
  `a  | N:3; a; b; c; |  ConsoleApplication1.MyList<string>`

In the console window it is written `N:3; a; b; c;`, which shows that the method and the overriding in principle do work. Also, calling a.ToString() in the Direct-Window shows the expected `N:3; a; b; c;`.

What am I missing?   How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829032/how-to-get-tostring-to-show-up-in-debug?

Comment: HimBromBeere's link solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: try this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829032/how-to-get-tostring-to-show-up-in-debug). i hope this will help you tosolvethe problem.