# Best practices: a Property, a Function or ToString?

Tags: c#, tostring, readability, maintainability

I am trying to determine a best practice when writing code to get the string representation of a custom class.

Imagine we have the following:

```
public class DoubleParameter
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Units { get; set; }
}
```

And we want the ability to get a string representation of the class for debugging purposes. Regarding code readability/maintainability and best practices, I'm evaluating three options

1. An Inline Property
2. A Custom Method
3. Overriding ToString()

Most of these are very similar from the compiler's point of view - but are there any objective reasons to prefer any particular option in terms of readability/maintainability?  Or is it a matter of personal preference?

Examples of use:

```
// Option 1 - Inline Property
public string ReadableValue => 
    $"{this.Description} => {this.Value.ToString("F2")} ({this.Units})";
// example usage: Console.WriteLine(myVar.ReadableValue);

// Option 2 - Custom Method
public string ToReadable() =>
    $"{this.Description} => {this.Value.ToString("F2")} ({this.Units})";
// example usage: Console.WriteLine(myVar.ToReadable());

// Option 3 - Overriding ToString()
public override string ToString() =>
    $"{this.Description} => {this.Value.ToString("F2")} ({this.Units})";
// example usage: Console.WriteLine(myVar);
```

Comment: Opinions are against the rules around here.

Comment: The `ToString` implementation has the advantage of making debugging way easier.  And, oh yeah, no opinions.

Comment: If this is just for debugging, `ToString()` is preferred. Don't forget about [DebuggerDisplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829032/how-to-get-tostring-to-show-up-in-debug)

Comment: I got it, no opinions is a must. But I think we can say something about objective aspects such as readability and/or maintainability, can't we?

Comment: I submitted an edit to make it less opinion-centric.  Hopefully it'll get accepted by the mods.  Because, to be honest, it's a good question.

Comment: @RicardoFuente Readability and maintainability aren't objective, they're extremely subjective and lots of people have different *opinions* on what is "readable" and what isn't.

Comment: We can also say objective things about the by-design purpose of a thing. The by-design purpose of `ToString` is to give a friendly, human-readable summary of the value of an object for display or debugging purposes. Are you intending to give a friendly, human-readable summary of the value of an object for display or debugging purposes? If yes, then why would you do something *other* than `ToString`?

Comment: That said, this is a perfectly reasonable question and it should not be closed or deleted.

Comment: The question "what are the Microsoft-blessed best practices encouraged by the designers of this method?" is also an objective question. If you have not already, you should read the "best practices" section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring

Comment: I tried editing, but it was rejected as 'superfluous' - that it didn't clarify or improve readability (even though it wasn't attempting to make it more readable).  I just wish the last paragraph simply asked if "there are objective reasons to prefer any of the options, or if it's simply a matter of personal preference."  Bam - it's no longer opinion-based, and is a good question for the site.

Comment: @Kevin Include more changes, such as removing the c# from the title since it's a tag.

Comment: Will attempt another edit.  But... it seems weird to reject an edit if I didn't find *all* the things to fix (instead of just the big thing that's putting the question on hold.)

Comment: @Kevin The title is problematic though too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging purposes, ToString() wins hands down.

Why?  Because when you're stepping through code using VisualStudio, VS will easily display the ToString() results when you hover over a variable, or put the variable in the watch window.  Otherwise, you have to dig in to get the property you're concerned with.  This can be especially annoying if you're working with lists/enumerations/etc.

Also, ToString() already exists, and is already *supposed* to be the text representation of an instance of your object.  That's the whole point of it.  Why add another property that's *also* the string representation of your object?

Comment: I'm kinda curious about the downvote - I think my answer's pretty straight-forward, concise, and factual.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: It is a mystery. This answer looks concise and factual to me.

Comment: In my Opinion, `ToString()` should be able to produce a serializable version of the underlaying object. Which means the string needs to contain everything required to deserialize it into the object again.

Therefore, `ToString()` should not be abused for some short-cut debug outputs of only a few properties of an object. (i.e. firstname / lastname of User) For that, use a custom property/method `DisplayName()` or something like that.

Comment: @dognose ToString is a function, not a property.

Comment: @dognose: Your opinion is not shared by the designers of the runtime. They note that **if the object is deserializable from a string, then you should consider making ToString produce the serializable form**.  That is a far weaker position than the strong position you are taking. They note that rather, the by-design purpose of ToString is to make a **short, friendly, human-readable, debugger-compatible summary of the state of an object**.

Comment: @dognose, That's not what ToString() is meant for.  There's a whole separate way of doing serialization in .net - you're not supposed to build your own, using the ToString() as a makeshift 'Serialize' function.  Plus, well, if you're debugging something in VS, the last thing you want to do is serialize a massive instance whenever you try to hover over a variable.

Comment: (That last part is *very* important.  ToString() is supposed to be a quick, low-cost function.  Serializing a massive data object might be a time-consuming task.)

Comment: @EricLippert True, but there is no reason as well, why one would violate that "advice" even for non-deserializable objects? Worst thing is inconsistency within the same application. Imagine: "Oh yeah, that one can be searialized by `ToString()` - No, here you need to use `ToSearializedString()`, cause we use `ToString()` for Textboxes only"

Comment: @dognose, now, do not fall into the pernicious trap of saying "My object is serializable as JSON, JSON is serializable as a string, therefore `ToString` should produce the JSON serialization."  That is not good logic and not good object design.  Rather, the object should implement serialization logic that traffics **in json objects**, and if the user wishes to convert those to or from strings, the user can do so.

Comment: @dognose: You should not use `ToString` for serialization to begin with. The advice is not "use ToString for serialization".  Use serialization methods for serialization. The advice is **if** an object has a serialized string form, then **consider** making ToString produce that form.  That consideration involves good judgment, and judgment is the art of making compromises when faced with conflicting goals.

Comment: @dognose In the scenario you described, `ToSerializedString()` would always be used return the serialized object (and do you mean json serialized, xml serialized, or something else, by the way?). [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) is for **display** purposes. If serialization was the main purpose, then wouldn't the default implementation use reflection to build a serialized representation of the type rather than just returning the fully-qualified **name** of the object's type?

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to make property private and use it internally as value for attribute [DebuggerDisplayAttribute] like this

`[DebuggerDisplay("{ReadableValue},nq")]
 public class DoubleParameter
 {
    private string ReadableValue { get; }
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all your comments.

I am in the line of most of you: use `ToString()` and it's good to know that I'm not alone. But in the end, it seems we are going to 'save' it for later logging purposes.

@LarsTech: Thanks for the edition, much clearer ;)